# Finding first tag in HTML file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a set of HTML files which I want to pull the first tag in each file. As the files don’t have a specific tag which will always be the first in the file, I’m not sure how to do this.

As an example, for the following snippet, the first tag would be `<html>`.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
     insert title here
    </title>
 </head>
</html>
```

Any way to accomplish this with BeautifulSoup (or possibly another tool)? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you have HTML files, why don't you just search the first line that start with `<` ?

Comment: I could, but since I have to use bs4 for other operations on the files anyways, I was wondering if there was something built in that could help. I’ll probably just do it like you say if I can’t find a better way

Comment: The first tag in all HTML documents is `<html>` so not sure what exactly is your question.

Comment: The HTML documents are not guaranteed to be proper which is why I’m asking. In addition, the files may have comments which may cause issues with just checking the first line that starts with `<`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` in this case, just issue [`find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) on a `BeautifulSoup` object - it would find the first element in the tree. [`.name`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name) would give you the tag name:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
     insert title here
    </title>
 </head>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print(soup.find().name)
```